# error: "'dict' object has no attribute 'lower'" when running scipy.optimization.minimize-function

Tags: dictionary, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm trying to use the function minimize from the scipy.optimize-package for my machine learning class. Python says:

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'lower'

What could give rise to a problem like this? I would be most grateful for answers!

Comment: `lower` is a method of Python strings.  The variable in question (which you don't show) is not a string.  We need to see some code and a traceback to help you.

Comment: Hi, please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you!

Comment: please refer to how to write a question